# How to get <a> tags in <body> but exclude header and footer sections

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

If I have a webpage like this:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <a href='http://domain1.com'>link 1 text</a>
  </header>

  <a href='http://domain2.com'>link 2 text</a>

  <footer>
    <a href='http://domain3.com'>link 3 text</a>
  </footer>
</body>
```

How do I pull the `<a>` tags out of the `<body>` but exclude the links from `<header>` and `<footer>`?

In the real web page, there will be a lot of `<a>` tags in the `<header>` so I'd rather not have to cycle through ALL of them.

I want to pull out the URLs and anchor text from each of the `<a>` tags that are NOT inside the `<header>` or `<footer>` tags.

EDIT: this is how I find links in the header:

```
$header = $html->find('header',0);
foreach ($header->find('a') as $a){
  do something
}
```

I would like to do this (note the use of "!")

```
$foo = $html->find('!header,!footer');
foreach ($foo->find('a') as $a){
  do something
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this with Javascript or PHP? Javascript would be significantly easier.

Comment: @JamesPaterson — The question is tagged both PHP and with a specific PHP DOM library, and not with JavaScript at all. It's safe to assume they are using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the header and footer from the DOM you are working with before looking for the links.

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $source = <<<EOD
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href='http://domain1.com'>link 1 text</a>
        </header>

        <a href='http://domain2.com'>link 2 text</a>

        <a href='http://domain4.com'>link 4 text</a>

        <footer>
            <a href='http://domain3.com'>link 3 text</a>
        </footer>
    </body>
EOD;

    $html = str_get_html($source);
    foreach ($html->find('header, footer') as $unwanted) {
        $unwanted->outertext = "";
    }
    $html->load($html->save()); 
    $links = $html->find("a");
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        print $link;
};

?>
```

Comment: Perfect. In my case I use `file_get_html` With the `save` function that you show, I'm now able to process the "new" `$html` further down the code without having to parse out header and footer tags again. Cheers for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Without mangling the body? You could do something like:

```
$bad_as = $html->find('header a, footer a');
foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
  if(in_array($a, $bad_as)) continue;
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with simple-html-dom, in simply way of course.
You can't do this with simple-html-dom.

```
$html->find('body > a');
```

This Css selector Selects all `<a>` elements where the parent is a `<body>` element.
You need to loop through body's children nodes and then get `<a>`

I suggest to look at [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

For my part, I'm using Symfony/DomCrawler and Symfony/CssSelector to do this.

Comment: That works for this specific example, where the desired links are *children* of the body element. Presumably, however, it is a simplified example and the links are going to be inside other elements (such as paragraphs).

Comment: Yes, and as I said, simplehtmldom is an **old** library, it doesn't support recent Css Selectors defined by **W3C**. If simple example is  complicated, what about if it's more complicated. ^^